# EMBERJS: I cannot retrieve the title and body from PostController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I am trying to follow the guide here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_templates-controllers-and-views

I saw this paragraph:

```
This connectOutlet call does a few things for us:

It creates a new instance of App.PostsView, using the posts.handlebars template.
It sets the content property of postsController to a list of all of the available posts (App.Post.find()) and makes postsController the controller for the new App.PostsView.
It connects the new view to the outlet in application.handlebars.
```

I believe I still have do create those files manually, right? If yes, follow up question is, for the PostController, what should it look like?

btw, I am using the ember-rails and used the generator for the structure.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ember-rails you can use `rails g ember:view Posts` to generate the PostsController, PostsView and posts.handlebars template all at once.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
On the PostsController, I still need to use ArrayController just to make the posts be listed.
How about on the PostController? What should I use for me to use post.title and post.body?

Comment: Your PostController can be an extension of `Ember.ObjectController`